# KittenPHP - что за зверь?

Tags: php

Всем привет! Сегодня, с чужой подачи, второй раз столкнулся с таким продуктом, как [KittenPHP](http://kittenphp.com/). Я всегда очень скептически отношусь к подобным фишкам, поэтому в первый раз просто проигнорировал. Как говорится: "*Один раз - случайность, два раза - закономерность*". Слегка удивляют результаты тестов, размещенные у них на главной. В общем-то, я и до сих пор с лёгкой иронией отношусь ко всему подобному, но если кто-то реально использовал или тестировал это "чудо", то хотелось бы узнать его мнение. Тратить время на какой-то очередной развод, у меня желания нет, но если это что-то более-менее реальное, то ... там будем поглядеть ;)

---

***Думаю, что не имеет смысла продолжать дискуссию, т.к. если бы в KittenPHP было что-то стоящее, то это уже как-нибудь проявилось.
Посему, считаю целесообразным закрыть вопрос, но если кому-то найдётся что дополнит по сути, то он переоткроет его.***

Comment: @Deonis, я так руками и не трогал, но ни доков, ни хороших примеров использования вы не найдете. При создании, насколько понимаю, у разработчиков не было в списке целей создать опенсурсный продукт которым смогут пользоваться все подряд. В общем, без необходимости, я бы не лез просто из-за того, что там будет сложно разобраться.

> Слегка удивляют результаты тестов

"мы выпилили все лишнее и скомпилировали на С". Хз, по-моему проще уже сам по себе движок писать сразу на сишке.

Comment: @Etki, значит, вы подтверждаете мою точку зрения. Кроме того, за час больше никаких мнений, а это тоже кое о чем говорит.

Answer (score 1):

PHP и так достаточно быстрый язык, и жертвовать массой его достоинств не стоит. Один этот пункт " в нем отсутствует ООП" уже делает разработку в разы сложнее, не дает пользоваться большинством библиотек и фреймворков.

А в большинстве приложений узким местом становится не PHP, а хранилище данных.
А анализ кода и в PHPStorm есть, и большую часть ошибок можно отловить заранее.

А тесты на главной странице - это не результат работы настоящего сложного приложения, которое будет работать совсем по другому.

Comment: @biohazardo, в любом случае, благодарю, сударь, за ваше мнение, однако, я попробовал (*видимо не достаточно*) акцентировать внимание на том, что могут сказать об этом всём люди, которые **реально опробовали** этот продукт. Я хоть и не такой профи, но делать выводы из просто прочитанного, мои пара извилин позволяют. Все мы знаем, что за забором, чаще всего, оказывается совсем не то, что на нём писали.